# how to store state using in sinatra using json/javascript without databases

Tags: javascript, sinatra

The html view of the app contains a variable which is by default set to 20. This temperature is then increased or decreased using a up/down button when running the app in the browser. However if the browser or page is refreshed (or redirected) temperature does not remain but instead always resets to 20.

Here is the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <html>   <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">   </head>   <body>
    <section class="display">
      <h1>Thermostat</h1>
      <input id='city' type='text' placeholder="city name">
      <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
      <p id='weather'></p>
      <h1 id="temperature"></h1>
      <h4 id="psm"></h4>
      <form action='/temperature' method='post'>
        <button class="icon icon-up" id="up" name='temp'></button>
        <button class="icon icon-down"id="down" name='temp'></button>
        <button id="reset" name='temp'>reset</button>
        <button id="switchpowersaving">PSM</button>
      </form>
    </section>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="thermostat.js"></script>
    <script src="interface.js"></script>
    <script src="weatherAPI.js"></script>   </body> </html>
```

When we visit the page we are directed to the index. Here we then increase/decrease the temperature. Every time temperature is changed a 'POST' method is sent to our /temperature page. This then creates a hash using JSON, sessions and parameters. This in the interface.js file there is an ajax GET function which stores this new temperature as data.temp. This should then set the thermostat.temperature to the stored data.temp everytime the page is reloaded. However it continually gets reset to 20.

This is the controller:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

enable :sessions

  get '/' do
    send_file 'views/index.html'
  end

  post '/temperature' do
    p params[:temp]
    session[:temp] = params[:temp].to_i
    redirect '/temperature'
  end

  get '/temperature' do
    p session[:temp]
    if session[:temp]
      JSON.generate({temp: session[:temp]})
    else
      JSON.generate({temp: 20})
    end
    redirect '/'
  end
```

Here is the interface.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var thermostat = new Thermostat();
  var temp = thermostat.temperature;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:4567/temperature',
    success: function(data){
      temp = data.temp;
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('Error loading temp');
    }
  });

  updateTemperature();

  $('#up').click(function() {
    thermostat.increaseTemperature();
    updateTemperature();
  });

  $('#down').click(function() {
    thermostat.decreaseTemperature();
    updateTemperature();
  });

  $('#reset').click(function() {
      thermostat.tempReset();
      updateTemperature();
    });

  $('#switchpowersaving').click(function() {
    thermostat.switchModePowerSaving();
    updateTemperature();
  });

    function updateTemperature() {
    $('#temperature').text(thermostat.currentTemperature() + "\xB0C");
    $('#up').attr('value', thermostat.currentTemperature());
    $('#down').attr('value', thermostat.currentTemperature());
    $('#reset').attr('value', thermostat.currentTemperature());
    $('.display').css('background-color', thermostat.displayColor());
    $('#psm').text(thermostat.displayPowerSaveMode());
  }
});
```

Here is the thermostat.js :

```
function Thermostat(){
  this.temperature = 20;
  this.MINTEMP = 10;
  this.isPowerSaving = true;
  this.thermostatDisplay = 'yellow';
}

Thermostat.prototype.currentTemperature = function(){
  return this.temperature;
};

Thermostat.prototype.increaseTemperature = function(){
  if ( this.currentTemperature() >= this.maxTemp()) {
    throw 'Max. temp reached';
}
  this.temperature ++;
};

Thermostat.prototype.decreaseTemperature = function(){
  if ( this.currentTemperature() <= this.MINTEMP ) {
    throw 'Min. temp reached';
  }
  this.temperature --;
};

Thermostat.prototype.maxTemp = function(){
  if(this.isPowerSaving === true) {return 25;}
    else
      {return 32;}
};

Thermostat.prototype.switchModePowerSaving = function() {
  if (this.isPowerSaving === true)
    {this.isPowerSaving=false;}
  else
    {this.isPowerSaving=true;}
};

Thermostat.prototype.tempReset = function() {
    this.temperature = 20;
};

Thermostat.prototype.displayColor = function() {
  if(this.temperature <= 18) {return 'green';}
  if(this.temperature <= 25) {return 'yellow';}
  if(this.temperature > 25) {return 'red';}
};

Thermostat.prototype.displayPowerSaveMode = function(){
  if(this.isPowerSaving === true) {return 'Power Save Mode: ON';}
  else {return 'Power Save Mode: OFF';}
};
```

The increaseTemperature/decreaseTemperature functions simply increase and decrease thermostat.temperature by +1/-1.

The new temperature when the button is pressed can be accessed when directly accessing '/temperature' in the browser however when redirected to the '/' the new thermostat.temperature is not set to the new temperature and always resets to the default temperature (20).

How can this be stored in state without using databases. (Store the new temperature so when the page is refreshed the new temperature remains rather than resetting to 20.

Comment: Are you sure the form is being submitted?  Why not just use $.ajax to update the temperature in real time?

Comment: the temperature previously was being updated in real time and there was no need for the controller however when refreshing the browser we require the temperature that the thermostat was at before being refreshed to be stored and retrieved. (the forms execute without and ajax.get scripts.) this was added for storing purposes only)

Comment: Hmm so Sinatra sessions are stored in cookies.  Perhaps you have them disabled in your browser?  Can you check that they cookie for your local domain is set?

Comment: yes cookies on my browser are enabled. However my feeling is that the ajax function is not setting temp = data.temp correctly as if I access the localhost:4657/temperature domain directly it returns the new temperature after increasetemperature is executed the first time (21). Then it returns to 20 when the page is redirected back to '/'.

Comment: Oh I see the problem now:  there are two things wrong here.  First, instead of assigning to `temp`, you want to assign to `thermostat.temperature`.  It seems like you're trying to do something that would work with pointers in C, but in JavaScript everything is a reference, and assigning to the variable doesn't do anything.  Second, you need to call updateTemperature from the `success` function.  Calling it after calling `$.ajax` does nothing, because the request is asynchronous.

Comment: @jjm i have edited it to

'var thermostat = new Thermostat();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:4567/temperature',
    success: function(data){
      thermostat.temperature = data.temp;
      updateTemperature();
    },
    error: function(){
      alert('Error loading temp');
    }
  });

  // updateTemperature();'

however now am receive undefined for the thermostat.temperature when running the app

Comment: Did it work with the edits?

Comment: @jjm haven't managed to get it to work. with the first change (setting it to thermostat.temperature rather than temp, the undefined error is received. with the second change (putting updateTemperature() inside the success function did not make any noticeable change.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here:

`send_file` is not the preferred way of loading a HTML file using Sinatra. The alternative to this is to rename the `index.html` to `index.erb` and then use the following as the route descriptor:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

ERB is a superset of HTML and adds ruby interpolation tags that can be used to pass variables from Sinatra or simply run ruby commands in the view. These tags are similar to JSP's `<%%>` or PHP's `<?php ?>` if you're familiar with those. In ERB, `<%%>` would run a ruby command, `<%= %>` can be used to print out the result of a ruby command onto the view.

It's important to figure out the data type of request/response upfront while designing the routes. For instance, when `interface.js` loads, it makes a `GET` request via jQuery to the `'/temperature` endpoint. Since you haven't specified the data type, the response would be a string and `data.temp` will be `null`. So in the ajax call, you'd need to add a `dataType: 'json'` setting:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:4567/temperature',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
  // same as earlier
});
```

One more good thing to do is not to mix and match AJAX calls and `redirect` calls in sinatra. This is a problem especially in this case because when you redirect to the index page, although the session data is present, it's not getting loaded/displayed anywhere. Ideally, in Sinatra you'd have to assign the value to an instance variable and print it out in the view:

```
# app.rb
get '/' do
  @temp = session[:temp] || 20
  erb :index
end

# views/index.erb
# truncating common code
<h1 id="temperature"><%= @temp %></h1>
```

That way, when the `get '/'` route loads, initial temperature is displayed. The `$.ajax` `GET` request can be removed entirely.

When buttons are clicked, by default the form submit happens which will do a full reload. This can mess up with any JS based rendering you are doing (I'm unable to understand that part entirely for now). So instead of doing a full page redirect, it's better to an AJAX post (like pointed out in the comments) to '/temperature' route. Note that you'd have to disable the default action of a button click. So:

```
  $('#up').click(function() {
    thermostat.increaseTemperature();
    updateTemperature();
   });
```

and other click handlers should be changed to:

```
  $('#up').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    thermostat.increaseTemperature();
    updateTemperature();
   });
```

This will ensure that the default HTML form submit doesn't happen when you click on the button. And `updateTemperature()` will make an ajax POST call. I've put up a sample here: https://gist.github.com/kgrz/9320d1682e682a9930c30e34c979a306

Comment: I have incorporated your syntax into our files however when we reload the page it seems as though the index does not have a session: temp and it defaults to 20 as per before. @Kashyap

Comment: I dont think the ajax.post function is inheriting the params[:temp]